# How to redirect /directory/index.html and /directory/index.php to /directory/

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have to do some redirects - index.html and index.php to /.

I could redirect `www.domain.com/index.html` and `www.domain.com/index.php` to `www.domain.com` with this line:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html?)$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

However I still have problems with pages like these:

- `www.domain.com/directory/index.html`   - returns **200 OK**
- `www.domain.com/directory/index.php`    - returns **300 multiple choices** (don't know why)

Is it possible to redirect them to `www.domain.com/directory/` and do it all with one rule one?

If this helps, here's what's in my .htaccess file now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## Redirecd index.html & php to /
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html?)$ http://www...mydomain...com/ [R=301,L]

## 301 Redirect from non-www to www version
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

## Return 404 status code and display 404.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## Redirecd index.html & php to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.(html|php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.(?:html|php)$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

## 301 Redirect from non-www to www version
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

## Return 404 status code and display 404.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try replacing your first rewriterule with following

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.+/)?index\.(php|html?)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This will cause looping if `index.html` or `index.php` are used in `DirectoryIndex`

Comment: thanks @anubhava for your comment, I didn't (and still havn't) test it with DirectoryIndex set to said files. Is there a way we can avoid such issue?

Comment: Yes it can be avoided by using `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}` as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. This works fine with any directory.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.(html|php)

RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(html|php)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```